# TclError: unknown option "-font" for button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am writing a function in python to display components of a window in tkinter. While displaying a button I get this error:

```
TclError: unknown option "-font"
```

Here is my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    import socket
    import psutil 
    from plyer import notification 
    master = Tk()
    navbar = Canvas(master,width=width,highlightthickness=0, height=60, bg='#0a2145')
    name = Label(master, text="Estancia", font=('Verdana',12,'italic'))
    name.config(background='#0a2145', foreground='white')   
    sys_det = Label(master, text='Estancia', font=('Verdana',32))
    sys_det.config(background='#304566',foreground='white')
    ID = Entry(master, font=('Verdana',10,'italic'), width=20)
    Pass = Entry(master, font=('Verdana',10),show='•', width=20)
    det_sub = Button(master, text = 'Submit',font=('Verdana',10), command=redirect, fg='white', bg='#304566', 
                    height=1, width=2)
    
    canvas1.create_window(50, 22, window=name)
    canvas1.create_window(680,20,window=navbar)
    canvas1.create_window(685,225,window=sys_det)
    canvas1.create_window(685,325,window=ID)
    canvas1.create_window(685,350,window=Pass)
    canvas1.create_window(685,380,window=det_sub)
```

Can anyone figure out what is the problem?

Comment: Probably you are using a Ttk `Button`, rather than the plain Tkinter version - you have to use Ttk's Style mechanism to customize its widgets.  (If you had posted a [mcve] as requested, we'd be able to see your import statements, and tell exactly which widgets you were using.)

Comment: I'll add the import statements.

Comment: When I removed font property, the console displays that there is an error in fg property of the button

Comment: You are using `ttk.Button` instead of `tkinter.Button` because `from tkinter.ttk import *` override `from tkinter import *`.  Avoid using `import *`, use `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import ttk` instead.  Then specify which `Button` you want, like `tk.Button`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Once you add it as an answer I'll be ready to accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is on how you import modules:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

Since both `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` have `Button` widget, so you are using `tkinter.ttk.Button` instead of `tkinter.Button`. `tkinter.ttk.Button` does not support `font` option.

Avoid using `import *`, use:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

Then specify which `Button` you want, like `tk.Button`.

Answer (score 3):

The comments have described your problem, but IMO they do not go deep enough in explaining your options or what your problem truly is. The error you are receiving is a symptom of your true problem, and that problem is `namespace pollution`. When you `from tkinter import *` you expose all the classes of the tk package. `ttk` has numerous classes that overlap `tk`. So, when you then `from tkinter.ttk import *` you are overwriting all redundant classes from the `tk` package.

The immediate fix is to stop polluting your namespace. You can do so like this: `import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk`. Now when you want to use a `tk` widget you simply prepend the class name with the `tk` alias. The same for `ttk`, but using the `ttk` alias.

TK Example:
`label = tk.Label(self, text="some text")`

TTK Example:
`label = ttk.Label(self, text="some text")`

---

With that problem out of the way you can focus on the next part. `tk` widgets expect you to put the options in either the class constructor or the `.configure()` method. `ttk` widgets expect you to create a style and apply the style to the widget. There are numerous syntax possibilities for creating a style that range from "very simple" to "quite complex". It would behoove you to research `ttk.Style` if you intend to use `ttk` widgets, and probably write some example codes so you can become accustomed to it's intricacies. Not to leave you without an example...

Complex example of a ttk style. This is meant to be a visual example to give you an idea of what to expect. I did not copy/paste every dependency of this script, and therefore, you cannot copy/paste it and expect it to run.

```
# Scrollbar
# states ~ active disabled
# NOTE: arrowsize will change the thickness of the scrollbar even if you rip the arrows out
@dataclass
class Scrollbar_dc:
    background:         String = Theme.Contrast
    bordercolor:        String = Theme.Base
    darkcolor:          String = Theme.Contrast
    lightcolor:         String = Theme.Contrast
    troughcolor:        String = Theme.Topcoat
    arrowcolor:         String = Theme.Trim
    gripcount:          Int = 3
    arrowsize:          Int = 14

class CustomTheme(Style):
    def __init__(self, basetheme='clam'):
        Style.__init__(self)
        
        self.theme_create('custom', basetheme, {
            'custom.Vertical.TScrollbar': {
                #this is a direct copy of the default layout
                #it is intended to be a reference against the arrowless version, for comparison purposes
                'layout': [('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough', 
                    {'sticky': 'ns', 'children': [
                        ('Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''}), 
                        ('Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': ''}), 
                        ('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})
                    ]}
                )],
                'configure': asdict(Scrollbar_dc())
            },
            'custom.Horizontal.TScrollbar': {
                'configure': asdict(Scrollbar_dc())
            },
            'arrowless.Vertical.TScrollbar': {
                'layout': [('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough',
                    {'sticky': 'ns', 'children': [
                        ('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})
                    ]}
                )],
                'configure': asdict(Scrollbar_dc()),                     # arrowsize will still size the scrollbar thickness
            },
            'arrowless.Horizontal.TScrollbar': {
                'layout': [('Horizontal.Scrollbar.trough',
                    {'sticky': 'we', 'children': [
                        ('Horizontal.Scrollbar.thumb', {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})
                    ]}
                )],
                'configure': asdict(Scrollbar_dc())                      # arrowsize will still size the scrollbar thickness
            }
        })
        self.theme_use('custom')
```